# Euler's Sieve for Totient Calculation

Tags: algorithm, math

Guys here is this algorithm for finding phi(i) = eulers totient(i) for all
1 <= i <= n.

```
int phi[n + 1];
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) phi[i] = i;
//invariant: phi(x) for all 1 <= x < d is calculated during the
//start of the dth iteration.
for (int d = 1; d <= n; ++d) { //divisors
    for (int j = 2 * d; j <= n; j += d) phi[j] -= phi[d];
}
```

[image]

How does the above formula help us implement the above algorithm?

Comment: i didn't downvote but this sounds like it might be homework, and it's not a clear question.

Comment: No, it's not homework, I am trying to understand the algorithm I found on codeforces. Basically I have done the sieving using euler's product formula using primes, but I wanted to understand this. Having difficulty understanding. So please help.

Comment: suggest asking on math.stackexchange instead

Comment: Stackoverflow feels hollow nowadays.

Comment: yeah, maybe. I'm usually one of the people to criticize it. But you're asking a math question, and this is a programming site. It's a math question because it requires someone to look at an algorithm and use discrete mathematics to figure out how to do.... something. What do you mean by "help us implement"? Don't you already have an algorithm? Or do you mean why does it work?

Comment: I thought about asking at math.stackexchange, but here I have got an algorithm but I need to understand the math part. I thought I would be criticized for posting codes in math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the formula you gave, if we take phi(n) out of the sigma, we get:

`Sigma[d|n,d!=n]phi(d) + phi(n) = n`

Therefore:

`phi(n) = n - Sigma[d|n,d!=n]phi(d)`

And this is what the algorithm does: For each `n`, it starts with a value of `n` and subtracts `phi(d)` for each divisor `d` of `n` except `n` itself. Note that this is done in a different order, by iterating over `d` in the outer loop and `n` in the inner one, because it's faster to find a number's multiples than to find its divisors.

Comment: OH shit! I was thinking where do I get phi(n) from the above formula, but was not counting n as the divisor of itself. MY BAD :(